# XmlTextReader/Writer глюк?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*VS2013 Ultimate Update 4*
*.Net 4.5*
пытаюсь выбрать класс XmlTextWriter / Reader, но студия его не отображает почему-то. Ссылки добавлены. У меня 2 мысли либо это глюк студии, либо это класс устарел, хотя обычно об этом предупреждает MSDN, да и сама студия тоже. Причем если соблюдая регистр, объявить этот класс, то он воспринимается студией. Может кто знает, что тут за глюк?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: просто глюк intellisense, бывает.

Comment: А исправить можно? А то перезагрузка компа не спасла положение.

Comment: В данном случае intellisense не виноват, но на будущее: обычно при его глюках помогает удаление файла .suo в папке проекта (и переоткрытие проекта). При этом потеряется вся информация об открытых файлах и т. п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классы `XmlTextReader` и `XmlTextWriter` являются устаревшими и помечены атрибутом `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`. Можете убедиться в этом, нажав F12 (Go To Definition), когда курсор на этих классах. Именно поэтому они не показываются интеллисенсом в редакторе.

Вместо них используйте классы [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [XmlWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Экземпляры классов создаются вызовом статического метода Create.

Comment: А Вы не подскажете как сейчас актуально записывать в XML, просто все те примеры, что я поcмотрел реализованы на XmlTextWriter/Reader? Каким классом пользоваться?

Comment: @Malcolm - обновил ответ.

Comment: Alexander Petrov - Спасибо за информацию.